# Showing Camera Preview not taking full screen

Tags: java, android, commonsware-cwac

I am using S3 With Camera.Size comes to be 720*1280 Same as the screen size.

However, The camera surface appears only like the picture below not covering full screen (Length wise yes but not width wise)

[image]

I tried setting

```
  @Override
  public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface,
                                        int width, int height) {
    this.surface=surface;

    cameraView.previewCreated();
    cameraView.initPreview(width, height);
  }
```

as

cameraView.initPreview(720, 1280);

But it had only negligible effect.

My question is, How can i make it expand to full screen like a Camera Application. What is going on in here.

Same results come up in Demo application. In my HTC results are better but still there are spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as designed, though what you want will be in the 0.6.0 version.

Quoting an upcoming version of the project `README`:

---

The default behavior of `CameraFragment` and `CameraView` is to show the entire
preview, as supplied by the underlying `Camera` API. Since the aspect ratio of
the preview frames may be different than the aspect ratio of the `CameraView`,
this results in a "letterbox" effect, where the background will show through on
one axis on the sides.

If you want the preview to completely fill the `CameraView`, at the cost of
cropping off some of the actual preview frame, have your `CameraHost`
return `true` from `useFullBleedPreview()`.

Note that the pictures and videos taken by this library are unaffected by
`useFullBleedPreview()`. Hence, if `useFullBleedPreview()` returns `true`, the
picture or video may contain additional content on the edges that was not
visible in the preview.

---

Support for `useFullBleedPreview()` will be in version 0.6.0 of the library, though the source code for it is already pushed to the repo and is available in the `master` branch. You are welcome to keep tabs on [this issue](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera/issues/52) for further developments.